# IONIC 5 don't post data to api php

Tags: php, ionic-framework

Please help...

I'm new in this forum.

I've an apllication that I will send to php api data to save into mysql.

My code Ionic 5

```
let headers     : any       = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

let item: {
  "nome" : "Sueli",
  "email" : "sueli16661@hotmail.com",
  "senha" : "123456",
  "nivel" : "admin"
}
var link = 'http://localhost/project2MJA/usuarios/criarUsuario.php';
var myData = JSON.stringify(item);

this.http.post(link, myData, headers)
.subscribe(data => {
console.log(data["_body"]); 
}, error => {
console.log(data['message']);
});
```

My code php

```
<?php
// headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X- 
Requested-With");

// obtém conexão
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instancia objeto usuário
include_once '../objects/usuario.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$usuario = new Usuario($db);

// recebe dados via POST - Body
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// certifica que os dados estão preenchidos
if(
!empty($data->nome) &&
!empty($data->email) &&
!empty($data->senha) &&
!empty($data->nivel)
){

// define as propriedades
$usuario->nome = $data->nome;
$usuario->email = $data->email;
$usuario->senha = $data->senha;
$usuario->nivel = $data->nivel;


// cria o usuário
if($usuario->criarUsuario()){

    // define código de resposta - 201 created
    http_response_code(201);

    // mensagem para o usuário
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Usuário criado com sucesso."));
}else{ // caso não cadastre o usuário exibe mensagem

    // define código de resposta - 503 service unavailable
    http_response_code(503);

    // mensagem de usuário não cadastrado
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Usuário não pode ser criado."));
}
}else{ // mensagem de dados incompletos

// define codigo de resposta - 400 bad request
http_response_code(400);

// mensagem para usuário
echo json_encode(array("message" => "Usuário não criado. Dados incompletos."));
}
```

I run ionic serve and test to save data and i receive the message:

POST http://localhost/project2MJA/usuarios/criarUsuario.php 400 (Bad Request)

[error from ionic][1]

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the value to `item`, you are declaring the type. In other words you are using `:` instead of `=`, it should be,

```
let item = {
  "nome" : "Sueli",
  "email" : "sueli16661@hotmail.com",
  "senha" : "123456",
  "nivel" : "admin"
}
```

That might be the problem.

BTW, I don't think you need the header and to stringify the data of the post. If I recall well (it's been several years since I do anything in PHP), you can get the values using `$_POST` in the backend (in your case as an example `$_POST['nome']`).

Comment: I used the JSON format that is being treated in the criarUsuario() method, and I'm not getting paid using $ _POST because I'm using http: //php.input. When I test the application by Postman it works by sending json, but in the ionic application it doesn't.